# How to swap linked list node in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to swap two linked list, my sorting function does't work. How can I swap the entire nodes. What I'm trying to do, is swap the whole list, instead of swapping it's members.

```
typedef struct    node
{
    char          *first_name;
    char          *last_name;
    struct node   *next;
}person;


person *new_p(char *name, char *last)
{
    person *p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(p));
    if (p)
    {
        p->first_name = name;
        p->last_name = last;
        p->next = NULL;
    }
    return (p);
}

void swap(person *a, person *b)
{
    person tmp;

    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void    sort(person *s)
{
     person *list;

    list = s;
    while (list->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(list->first_name, list->next->first_name) > 0)
        {
            swap(list, list->next);
        }
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough here to diagnose the problem.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so a full answer can be given. But it looks most likely because the `next` pointers have not been updated correctly (or at all). In fact, swapping nodes in a linked list should only require changing the `next` pointers and not copying the whole node.

Comment: @kaylum here's complete code http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/da81PB

Comment: `p = malloc(sizeof(p)); ` ==> `p = malloc(sizeof *p);`

Comment: you want to change a->b->c->d to what order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swap function mixes node data and node pointers, so the data (including the data related to the `next` pointer) is being "swapped"...

... this mixup could cause memory leaks and the node chain to break. If you're lucky, the chain will remain intact, but you'll be swapping a whole subsection rather then just two nodes.

To swap node data, consider (this is untested code):

```
// ugly, but should work
typedef struct node {
  char* first_name;
  char* last_name;
  struct node* next;
} person;

void swap(person* a, person* b) {
  person tmp;
  tmp.first_name = a->first_name;
  tmp.last_name = a->last_name;
  a->first_name = b->first_name;
  a->last_name = b->last_name;
  b->first_name = tmp.first_name;
  b->last_name = tmp.last_name;
}
```

Or this (less ugly and easier to maintain):

```
typedef struct {
  char* first_name;
  char* last_name;

} person_s;

typedef struct person_nd person_nd;

struct person_nd {
  person_s data;
  person_nd* next;
};

void swap2(person_nd* a, person_nd* b) {
  person_s tmp;
  tmp = a->data;
  a->data = b->data;
  b->data = tmp;
}
```

These are all ugly solution. The correct way would be to leave the data as is and swap the position of the nodes.

The requires us to know more information about the node list structure, specifically the address of the pointers referencing the nodes.

On the other hand, this type of solution is data independent, so updates to the data structure shouldn't require rewriting the implementation.

i.e. (this will definitely fail, but it should demonstrate the concept):

```
void swap3(person_nd** a, person_nd** b) {
  person_nd* tmp = *a;
  // swap the position in the tree.
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
  // swap the "forward" branches
  tmp = (*a)->next;
  (*a)->next = (*b)->next;
  (*b)->next = tmp;
}
```